# В чем разница между @Valid и @Validated в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Есть класс, где я использую аннотации @NotNull и @NotBlank. На этот класс нужно добавить валидацию?
Какая разница между @Valid и @Validated?

Comment: Я, конечно, не имею ничего против таких вопросов. Но неужели задать вопрос на СО легче, чем потратить 10 секунд на запрос в гугле? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring

Comment: @NarasuOo база на enSO != база на ruSO. Вы даже можете перевести вопрос и ответ с английского сайта на русский, и если вопрос\ответ действительно полезный, срубить плюсиков.